# Is there a way of conditionally selecting which WHERE-clause to use in an SQL query?

Tags: sql, t-sql, where-clause

Knowing I have 2 variables declared called @Variable and @Name, I need something like this:

```
SELECT * from (myDbTable)
CASE WHEN (@Variable IS NOT NULL AND @Variable <> '')
THEN WHERE myDbTable.variable LIKE @Variable
ELSE WHERE myDbTable.name LIKE @Name
```

Basically, if the user enters a "variable" value, it should do a WHERE-clause on that variable, if not, it should do a WHERE-clause on Name.

Can I do this in SQL?

Comment: No, you cannot use logical flow operations inside a query. You would need to use `AND` and `OR` logic, write multiple statements and which is run is determined by `IF...ELSE` statements, or you could use dynamic SQL (no likely the solution here, if i am honest).

Comment: you need to check your @variable and execute the desired statement using `sp_executesql`

Answer (score 1):

This would do the work(Not the most efficient though):

```
SELECT * from (myDbTable)
WHERE ((@Variable IS NOT NULL AND @Variable <> '') AND myDbTable.variable LIKE @Variable)
OR ((@Variable IS NULL OR @Variable = '') AND myDbTable.name LIKE @Name)
```

You can also use `dynamic sql` like suggested in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options here:

#### Use boolean logic

```sql
SELECT *
FROM dbo.myDbTable
WHERE (@Variable IS NOT NULL AND @variable != '' AND variable LIKE @Variable)
   OR ((@Variable IS NULL OR @Variable = '') AND [Name] LIKE @Name)
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

The `RECOMPILE` is added to the `OPTION` clause, as very likely the plans for the 2 variables could be very different. This means that a plan relevant to the valueof `@variable` (if it's `NULL`/`''` or not) will be used.

#### Use `IF...ELSE` logic

```sql
IF NULLIF(@Variable,'') IS NOT NULL
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.myDbTable
    WHERE variable LIKE @Variable;
ELSE
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.myDbTable
    WHERE [Name] LIKE @Name;
```

Considering the simplicity of your query, this might be the "better" option, as the plans can be cached for the 2 different queries.

#### Dynamic SQL

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

SET @SQL = N'SELECT *' + @CRLF +
           N'FROM dbo.myDbTable' + @CRLF +
           N'WHERE ' + CASE WHEN NULLIF(@Variable,'') IS NOT NULL THEN N'variable LIKE @Variable'
                                                                  ELSE N'[Name] LIKE @Name'
                       END + N';';

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL, N'@Variable varchar(50), @Name varchar(50)', @Variable, @Name; --Data types are guessed.
```

This, like the `IF...ELSE` solution will have cached plans, however, I feel that this is an over complication of what you have. If you don't understand the importance of well written dynamic SQL, and the dangers of poorly written dynamic SQL, you shouldn't be using this.